# How to prevent key-bound functions to run if that key is pressed outside the menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So I've made a game-type of app which shows a question and gives 2 options, show answer and guess answer to keys [z] and [x] respectively. like this:

```
$('body').keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 18) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // CSS changes for Show Answer
    } else if (e.keyCode == 17) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // CSS changes for Guess Answer
    } else {});
```

the problem I have here is, The whole game has a long sequence on how things happen. and no matter which part of it you are, if you click [z] or [x], the CSS changes i've written above take place and make a huge mess. So how do I prevent this block of code from running once an option is chosen until next question?

Comment: You could simply use a variable to track whether the keyup handlers are supposed to run or not, and check on that with an `if` statement inside your handler. It's hard to show you explicit code to write because it's not clear when you want that variable turned on/off, but hopefully that gives you the idea.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Ohhh, yeah... Wonder why I didn't think about it haha. Thanks mate, Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a qChanging variable and at first set it to false.

`let qChanging = false;`


When the question is getting changed, set it to true. Then, change your keypress function to the code shown below.

```js
$("body").keyup(function (event) {
    if (!qChanging) {
        if (event.key == "x" || event.key == "X") {
            // x was pressed
        }
        else if (event.key == "z" || event.key == "Z") {
            // z was pressed
        }
    }
});
```

When your question has finished changing, set qChanging to false.


**DO NOT USE EVENT.KEYCODE**

**event.keyCode** is **deprecated**. You should use **event.key** or **event.code**. There are tutorials at the following links.


[event.key](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key)

[event.code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code)